C & Unix on Kubernetes - exit(0) doesn't work
I tried to run my C-program on my local kubernetes-cluster and on the first look all functions are working as I expect.
Only my signal-handler for terminating one process doesn't work completely.
There are two processes, one  for administration, one for the "work". The administration-process sends a SIGTERM to the worker-process and the signal-handler also catch this signal (I can see it in my logs). The only thing that does not work: terminating the worker-process.
Here the signal-handler:
void handle_sigterm() {
error_msg(sip_man_log, "(MAIN) INFO: Closing all sockets.");
close(connfd); 
close(sockfd); 
close(sockfd_ext);
free_manipulation_table(int_modification_table);
free_manipulation_table(ext_modification_table); 
free_manipulation_table(mir_modification_table);

error_msg(sip_man_log, "(MAIN) INFO: Terminating Server by SIGTERM"); 
exit(0);} 

In the logs the last message is visible but the process is still active so I think the "exit(0);" does not work correctly (on my mind the "exit(0)" should terminate the complete process).
If I try the same code on my local machine it works as I expect. I'm relative new in C and Unix-programming so I don't understand whats wrong here.

How was the "worker" process created? Through fork in the "administration" process? Then does the parent "admin" process wait for the child-process anywhere?

exit() is not safe to use in a signal handler. Need to make sure everything in those other functions it calls is safe, too. See https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

You either need to make sure that every thing you do in the signal handler is safe (which can be difficult, especially if this is new to you) or stop doing work in the signal handler.  It is generally sufficient to have the signal handler do nothing but assign a value to a global variable, and then have the main execution loop of the code check that value so that all of your cleanup and termination code is executing outside the signal handler.  That is (usually/almost always) the more robust approach.

Please provide a [mcve].

Ok, I will try to answer all the questions:

The worker-process is not started with fork. Admin and worker are independent. The admin-process start the worker-process with the system()-command.
My program is waiting for an incoming network-connection and my goal was to terminate the while-loop with the signal-handler. Is this also possible with a signal-handler only changing the value of a global variable? I will try that when I'm at home again.


Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. Don't use comments for this purpose. Hint for a solution with only setting a variable in the signal handler: Read the documentation of the functions you use and search for EINTR. Show a [mre], then we can propose a solution.

You can post an answer to your own question, and after a grace period, you can even accept it as "the correct answer". That removes your question from the list of open questions as well, which a "[SOLVED]" in the title does not. ;-)

I found a solution for my problem. I think this was a kubernetes-specific thing.
After some research I found out that the worker-process get the status Zombie after sending the SIGTERM and the parent-process was not able to clean up the Zombie.
So after adding tini as init-process (on dockerfile and deployment.yaml) and make sure it gets PID1 now the zombies are cleaned up and the worker-process is terminating when I send the SIGTERM from the admin-process.
I also tried to improve my signal-handler to make it safe again (thanks for your information in the comments). Now here the updated signal-handler and some parts of the rest of the program:
volatile atomic_int execute_loop = 1; 

void handle_sigterm() {
    error_msg(sip_man_log, "(MAIN) INFO: Signal reached.");
    execute_loop = 0; 
    error_msg(sip_man_log, "(MAIN) INFO: Closing all sockets.");
    close(sockfd_ext);
    close(connfd); 
    close(sockfd); 
}

int main()
{
    struct sockaddr_in  sockaddr, connaddr, sockaddr_ext;
    unsigned int        connaddr_len;
    char                buffer[8192];
    int                 rv, rv_ext;

    signal(SIGTERM, handle_sigterm); 
    
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    [...]

    while(execute_loop)
    {
        connaddr_len = sizeof(connaddr);
        connfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&connaddr, &connaddr_len);
    [...]
    }
    free_manipulation_table(int_modification_table);
    free_manipulation_table(ext_modification_table); 
    free_manipulation_table(mir_modification_table);
    error_msg(sip_man_log, "(MAIN) INFO: Terminating Server by SIGTERM"); 

    return 0;
}

It's very shortened and I skipped most of the error-handling.
Thanks for your help!
Dennis
